# Is it possible to write unit tests for select2 using jest?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, jquery-select2

we have an angular (7) application and we use on some pages the select2 library ([select2](https://select2.org)). I have lately changed the unit test runner from karma to jest. All the tests that contain the select2 component are broken. I have tried to add on setupJest.ts the below line:

```
global.$.fn.select2 = require('select2');
```

But nothing happened. The tests throw the below error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'select2' of undefined
```

I have not figure out how we could solve this problem.

Comment: Can you share a simple test that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution, but as a workaround for me, I've found that the downgrading to select2@4.0.3 helps. Tests pass with that version.